# Missing Questions after Site Update?

Tags: support, questions, maintenance

It seems some questions that were posted shortly before it went down are now gone. Will they ever come back or was the site restored from an earlier backup?

Here is an example: [Missing Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910722/answer/submit)

It was a question from someone else that I was going to answer when the site was locked.  When I came back after the site became unlocked, this happened.

Comment: Do you have links that at one time pointed to questions, and now do not? If so, post them here.

Comment: I don’t miss any question …

Comment: That question's not really "gone" The link returns a 500 status code. There's something there, but the site is having trouble showing it to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uh, that's not a proper link to a question - that's the interim URL you'd perhaps have seen *while posting an answer*.

The link you want is here: [play mp3 from network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910722/play-mp3-from-network)

The whole point of throwing the sites into "readonly" mode during the migration was to prevent folks from posting stuff that would be gone after the migration finished. So unless you were able to circumvent the readonly restrictions, nothing should be lost.